# Why is span-number not applied in blueprint?

Tags: css, blueprint-css

I have some textfields with the class `span-4` and they are nicely styled and aligned. When I try to apply the same classes to upload fields it seems as they have no effect. I also tried other span number, but still nothing happens.

How do we handle upload field styling with blueprint?

Answer (score 1):

An upload field is not handled in the same way as normal fields, there's a [helpful guide on how to custumize upload inputs](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html) - This article should take you through what is possible and what's not.